# A question about usage of 'Neither ... Nor...is'

Tags: grammar

**'Neither the dog, nor is the cat responsible for this mess.'** Is this statement correct? Shouldn't it be **'Neither the dog, nor the cat is responsible for this mess.'**

Comment: Yes it should; at least, that's the usual way of saying it.

Comment: However, the source I am referring to shows the former as a correct way of writing.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: A 2020 admission test paper of Xavier's Labour Research Institute, India.

Comment: Well, it seems a very odd construction to me. _Neither is the dog, nor the cat..._ is just possible, though it sounds stilted, but _Neither the dog, nor is the cat..._ is really bizarre.